# androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen not found when creating Preferences screen

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-preferences, preferencefragment

After following [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/) to create a screen for preferences, there seems to be a problem with inflating the class 'androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen'. Why is it not found when my preferences have been declared inside the `res/xml` folder and the necessary dependency has been added to this project?

My app's minSdkVersion is 24.

> Error inflating class (not found)androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen

**dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**res/xml/preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="preference_a"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:title="Preference A" />

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

**Activity layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/settings_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MySettingsActivity" />
```

Activity class

```
class MySettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings_container, MySettingsFragment())
                .commit()
    }
}
```

Fragment class

```
class MySettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences)
    }
}
```

Comment: As of 2019/04/10, there is an obvious mistake in the settings [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/). They forgot to call setContentView in the activity.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're using AndroidX, you should update your dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-preference-v14:1.0.0"
implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0"
```

The legacy is for the old `com.android.support:preference-v14` while the other is for `com.android.support:preference-v7`.

If you don't use AndroidX but Android Support libraries, do not import AndroidX widgets into your XML.

Comment: My app's minSdkVersion is 24. Do I still need to use the legacy one? Please check my **dependencies** list.

Comment: You're using an AndroidX widget in our XML yet your dependency is for a Support widget!

Comment: Ok. That's why, but this was not mentioned in the Android Developers tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use `PreferenceFragmentCompat` first you need to implement the following dependency in you app level gradle.

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0
```

Comment: Try to be more specific. Analyze your answer.

Answer (score 0):

With support libraries `28.0.0` you should have XML code like this:
(**NOTE** remove `androidx` for this case)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="preference_a"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:title="Preference A" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

and `gradle` config file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
```

and the implementation like this: 
(**NOTE**: `set` instead of `add` and `rootKey`):

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    public static final String TAG = SettingsFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
    }
}
```

In the [oficial documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/#java), they have **androidx** in the sample code, maybe that is the problem, you don't need it with support libraries

Comment: Code needs to be in Kotlin NOT Java

Comment: it's the same. Follow the link on the end.

Comment: I’m using AndroidX for my project